# Fbprophet raises error before object creation

Tags: python, time, series

Hello I am new to using `fbprophet`, getting following error

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
import plotly
import pandas as pd

pro = Prophet()
```

raises

`AttributeError: 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend'`

Comment: did you install the `fbprophet` module

Comment: @RajuKomati yes. It was installed correctly. Even updated it once with version 0.6

Comment: but when i run above code i am not getting any error

Comment: Don't know why I am getting this.

Comment: add the full code

Comment: This the full code. Since this is the initial phase a module.

Comment: there is no problem with code try reinstalling the module

Comment: Solved! there was the issue relaled to jupyter. I was not  able to use that required python executable. Python and ipython executable were referencing different paths for solution I updated the jupyter, By:

`pip install --upgrade jupyter'

Comment: Resintall miniconda, and required modules for fbprophet, still problem. `code` from fbprophet import Prophet
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('fbprophet')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

m = Prophet()
print(m.stan_backend)